# How to select a range with xlwings?

Tags: python, xlwings

I am attempting to select a range in order to freeze panes to a specific cell using xlwings.

```py
import xlwings as xw

wb_output = xw.Book(output_file_path, update_links=False)
main_sheet = wb_output.sheets[main_sheet_name]

main_sheet.activate()
main_sheet.range('C3').api.Select()
print(f'Current Selection = {xw.apps.active.selection.address}')

main_sheet.api.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

My code is not working, as the output is "Current Selection = $AK$883" instead of cell C3.

I have been reading the [xlwings documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.select), and this appears to be the correct way to select a cell, yet it is not working, so what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Your method does work but this method from Felix may be better for you [How to freeze pane in XLWings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57964966/13664137)